# Complexification the real inner product space

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $V$ be a real inner product space. If $W=V\times V$ with the operations
$(u_1,v_1)+(u_2,v_2)=(u_1+u_2,v_1+v_2)$ and $(\alpha +i\beta)(u,v)=(\alpha u-\beta v,\alpha   v+\beta u)$, where $u, u_1,u_2,v,v_1,v_2\in V$ and $\alpha,\beta$ are scalars.

> Show that $W$ is a complex inner product with the inner product
>   $$\langle (u_1,v_1),(u_2,v_2)\rangle=\langle u_1,u_2\rangle+\langle v_1,v_2\rangle+i\langle v_1,u_2\rangle-i\langle u_1,v_2\rangle$$

I do not know how to connect these operations, plz help

Comment: Do you know what an inner product is and what properties it satisfies?

Comment: @PandaBear yes, I want to apply the properties of the given inner product (for $W$).

Comment: That doesn't sound right.  You need to verify that the properties of an inner product are satisfied by the binary map supplied in your problem.

Answer (score 3):

A $\bf{\text{real inner product}}$ on $V$ is defined as a binary map $\langle\cdot, \cdot\rangle:V\times V\to \mathbb{C}$ with the properties:

1) $\langle u, u\rangle \geq 0$ for all $u\in V$ with equality only if $u = 0$

2) $\langle u, v\rangle = \langle v, u\rangle$ for all $u,v\in V$

3) $\langle k u,v\rangle = k \langle u,v\rangle$ for all $k\in\mathbb{R}, u,v\in V$.

As a consequence of 2 and 3, a real inner product is also linear in its second coordinate.

---

A $\bf{\text{complex inner product}}$ on $W$ is defined as a binary map $\langle\cdot, \cdot\rangle:W\times W\to \mathbb{C}$ with the properties:

1) $\langle x, x\rangle \geq 0$ for all $x\in W$ with equality only if $x = 0$

2) $\langle x, y\rangle = \overline{\langle y, x\rangle}$ for all $x,y\in W$

3) $\langle \alpha x,y\rangle = \alpha \langle x,y\rangle$ for all $\alpha\in\mathbb{C}, x,y\in W$.

As a consequence of 2 and 3, a complex inner product is conjugate-linear in its second coordinate.

---

Denote the bilinear map given in the question by $\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle_{W}$, and denote the real inner products on $V$ by $\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle$.  It is important to distinguish between these two.  The idea behind this problem is to $\bf{\text{use}}$ the fact that $\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle$ is a real inner product to $\bf{\text{prove}}$ that $\langle \cdot, \cdot\rangle_{W}$ is a complex inner product.

Let's check that the first property is satisfied.  Let $x = (u,v)\in W$, so that $u,v\in V$.

\begin{eqnarray*}
\langle x, x\rangle_{W} &=& \langle u, u \rangle + 
\langle v, v \rangle + i\langle v, u \rangle - i\langle u, v \rangle\\
&=& \langle u, u \rangle + 
\langle v, v \rangle + i\langle u, v \rangle - i\langle u, v \rangle\\
&=& \langle u, u \rangle + \langle v, v\rangle\\
&\geq& 0
\end{eqnarray*}
and the only way we can get equality is if $u = 0$ and $v = 0$.  In this case we have $x = (0,0)$, which establishes the first property.

The other two properties can be similarly verified.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Please do the 2nd property I have tried but I could not follow it.

Comment: Please edit your question to include the details of what you have tried, so I can better help you.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe too late, $\langle u_1+iv_1,u_2 + iv_2\rangle $ works as in $\mathbb{C}=\mathbb{R}+i\mathbb{R}$ i.e.,
$ (u_1+iv_1)\overline{(u_2+iv_2)}= (u_1+iv_1)(u_2-iv_2)=u_1u_2+v_1v_2+i(v_1u_2-u_1v_2)$. This definition inherits all the good properties from the original inner product $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle_V$.